# install osgi.bundle; org.objectweb.asm 7.0.0 for eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I try to install the Bytecode Outline plugin for eclipse.
During that I get the following error:

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could
>   not be found. Software currently installed: Bytecode Outline
>   1.0.0.201901132101-8614914 (org.eclipse.jdt.bcoview.feature.feature.group
>   1.0.0.201901132101-8614914) Missing requirement: Bytecode Outline 1.0.0.201901132101-8614914 (org.eclipse.jdt.bcoview 1.0.0.201901132101-8614914)  **requires 'osgi.bundle; org.objectweb.asm 7.0.0'** but it could not be found Cannot satisfy dependency: From: Bytecode Outline 1.0.0.201901132101-8614914
>   (org.eclipse.jdt.bcoview.feature.feature.group
>   1.0.0.201901132101-8614914) To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.jdt.bcoview
>   [1.0.0.201901132101-8614914,1.0.0.201901132101-8614914]

Now how can I install `osgi.bundle; org.objectweb.asm 7.0.0`?

Answer (score 5):

This means it requires asm 7.0.0 to be installed in the platform (can be installed from  [eclipse orbit repo](https://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20190226160451/repository/))

Answer (score 0):

`org.objectweb.asm` is part of the PDE component of core Eclipse. Version 7.0.0 is in Eclipse 2018-12 (Eclipse core 4.10), so you need to be using that version of Eclipse.

Comment: I am using eclipse 4.10, I downloaded it yesterday.

Comment: The plugin is included in the PDE (Plug-in Development Environment) component - make sure you have that installed, some installs don't include it

Comment: For Eclipse 4.11, the _Plug-in Development Environment_ isn't enough, you need to get a number of dependencies from the eclipse orbit repo.