# Java bytecode viewer for eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, bytecode

For several years I've used the Eclipse Bytecode Outline plugin for my compiler course that I give every other year. Now, it seems like it's no longer working. Trying to install it gives an error:

```
   Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
   Software currently installed: Bytecode Outline 1.0.1.202006062100 (org.eclipse.jdt.bcoview.feature.feature.group 1.0.1.202006062100)
   Missing requirement: Bytecode Outline 1.0.1.202006062100 (org.eclipse.jdt.bcoview 1.0.1.202006062100) requires 'osgi.bundle; org.objectweb.asm.analysis 7.0.0' but it could not be found
   Cannot satisfy dependency:
   From: Bytecode Outline 1.0.1.202006062100 (org.eclipse.jdt.bcoview.feature.feature.group 1.0.1.202006062100)
   To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.jdt.bcoview [1.0.1.202006062100,1.0.1.202006062100]
```

Is there a replacement or a fix for this?

Comment: The error says you're missing org.objectweb.asm.analysis 7.0.0.  Download and install the missing plugin first.

Comment: Do you have a link for this that works with any instructions for installing it? I've spent most of the day trying to find it and get it right, but haven't had much luck.

Comment: Here's one [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55002772/install-osgi-bundle-org-objectweb-asm-7-0-0-for-eclipse).  It appears you need to download the PDE version of Eclipse.

Comment: I think I'm giving up on this one. There are some serious version mismatches. It clearly requires objectweb.asm.analysis7.0.0. The current PDE version still has the problem. I can't fine a way to get that version of installing the asm.analysis into Eclipse. It's not worth the trouble. :-) The students can use javap -c to look at the bytecode. Thanks anyway for the help.